# Python 3: plot surface with no color in some points

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, surface

Let's say I have a 2D array such as:

```
Z = np.array([[    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0, 26067, 26067, 26750, 26750,     0,     0, 26673, 26673,            0,     0, 24411, 24411,     0,     0, 45494, 45494,     0],
   [    0, 26067, 26067, 26750, 26750,     0,     0, 26673, 26673,            0,     0, 24411, 24411,     0,     0, 45494, 45494,     0],
   [    0, 26750, 26750,     0,     0, 21237, 21237, 25516, 25516,        25839, 25839,     0,     0,     0,     0, 41704, 41704,     0],
   [    0, 26750, 26750,     0,     0, 21237, 21237, 25516, 25516,        25839, 25839,     0,     0,     0,     0, 41704, 41704,     0],
   [    0,     0,     0, 21236, 21236, 26414, 26414,     0,     0,        22847, 22847,     0,     0, 27051, 27051,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0,     0,     0, 21236, 21236, 26414, 26414,     0,     0,        22847, 22847,     0,     0, 27051, 27051,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0, 26673, 26673, 25516, 25516,     0,     0, 26414, 26414,            0,     0,     0,     0, 45013, 45013,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0, 26673, 26673, 25516, 25516,     0,     0, 26414, 26414,            0,     0,     0,     0, 45013, 45013,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0,     0,     0, 25839, 25839, 22860, 22860,     0,     0,        26213, 26213, 39181, 39181,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0,     0,     0, 25839, 25839, 22860, 22860,     0,     0,        26213, 26213, 39181, 39181,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0, 24411, 24411,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,        39183, 39183,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0, 24411, 24411,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,        39183, 39183,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 27052, 27052, 45015, 45015,            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 27052, 27052, 45015, 45015,            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0, 45494, 45494, 41434, 41434,     0,     0,     0,     0,            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0, 45494, 45494, 41434, 41434,     0,     0,     0,     0,            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
   [    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0]])

X = np.array([[ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  3.5,  3.5,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,         5.5,  6.5,  6.5,  7.5,  7.5,  8.5,  8.5]])

Y = np.array([[ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,         0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,         0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,         1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5],
   [ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,         1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5],
   [ 2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,         2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5],
   [ 2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,         2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5],
   [ 3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,         3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5],
   [ 3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,         3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5],
   [ 4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,         4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5],
   [ 4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,         4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5,  4.5],
   [ 5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,         5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5],
   [ 5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,         5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5,  5.5],
   [ 6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,         6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5],
   [ 6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,         6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5],
   [ 7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,         7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5],
   [ 7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,         7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5,  7.5],
   [ 8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,         8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5],
   [ 8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,         8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5]])
```

And I plot the surface using this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.plasma) #inferno, plasma, jet, sismic...
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
```

I do not want matplotlib to plot (or Paint) the big lower-east area with 0s, so instead of the color related to the 0 value I want to see the background color (or transparent color).

In MATLAB I can do that assigning `NaN` to the values you do not want to see. I tried with `math.nan` but it does not work. How can I do that in Python 3.6?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried numpy.nan?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using NaNs you can achieve this by masking the cells you want to be ignored. Matplotlib will see the masked values and simply not plot them.

```
numpy.ma
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/maskedarray.html

You can mask the array by feeding a boolean array as indices or masking each cell individually; it's a very flexible module.

```
X = np.ma.masked_where(X>0.5, X)
```

for example.

EDIT: I know this is the behaviour in 2D although I'm not sure about 3D. It is not clear to me which OP's problem concerns.

Comment: It Works in 2D, but you are right not working in 3D. Just fine by now.